# Custom SSIS data flow component with multiple output in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis

I am building a Custom SSIS data flow control which will provide three out put flow based on some rules validation. Please help me what exactly I need to implement in ProcessInput method  to redirect data in these three output based on the  some logic applied on the input

[image]

Comment: Depends on your logic. Are you certain this needs to be implemented this way? I know the idea of a custome data flow component seems to make sense - you can reuse it and it's full of familiar .Net goodness. But there is a lot of overhead with regards to deployment complications, maintenance complications and lastly, it's quite possible it won't perform well for large recordsets. How many records do you expect to flow through it?

Comment: Just consider that you won't get much help from here until you make an effort. I suggest you start reading this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136078.aspx write some code and ask some specific questions when you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to route each 1 of the 3 outputs from the <kbd>Custom Control</kbd> component shown in your data flow, to various different destinations based on conditions. For that, you could use a CONDITIONAL SPLIT Component as shown below.

You can split the input into 2 or more row streams by giving the CONDITIONAL SPLIT various conditions that look at column values etc.

[image]

If my understanding is incorrect, then please update your question with more details on your situation.

Comment: Shiva thanks for the suggestion. But I want some code will decide the path rather than using conditional split. I have three out puts 1. Information 2. Error 3. Warning. Based on my logic in ProcessInput method I need to route them in different paths. Is there something like buffer.DirectRow(), buffer.DirectErrorRow() to send data in different output from the customcontrol.

Comment: It's very difficult to help unless you update your question with more details. For example what is "ProcessInput"? What's in the Custom Control? Is it generating OutPut Rows? Or is it firing methods??